# Creating Top Values Query For SQL Report

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble with Creating Top Values Query For SQL Report.

I have a table (Cohorts), in my database where I have the following columns

`CUML_DEBT_P90  CUML_DEBT_P75   CUML_DEBT_P25   CUML_DEBT_P10`

I need to create the correct sql code to do the following and am having problems.  My problem is I am not too familiar with SQL and am having trouble with syntax and parameters.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- 10 highest and lowest schools for loan debt at 10% degree completion
- 10 highest and lowest schools for loan debt at 25% degree completion
- 10 highest and lowest schools for loan debt at 75% degree completion
- 10 highest and lowest schools for loan debt at 90% degree completion

I am using **SQL Server 2012** via the management studio

SQL statement select top 10 * from Cohorts order by CUML_DEBT_P10 desc

results 14177 11250 10000 9500 9299 8544 8350 8250 8125 8108

however this is not showing the top ten highest values of the entire data set for that column,/ the hi0ghest value for this column is 2172

data types in table are

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cohorts](
[UNITID] [float] NULL,
[INSTNM] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[CUML_DEBT_N] [float] NULL,
[CUML_DEBT_P90] [float] NULL,
[CUML_DEBT_P75] [float] NULL,
[CUML_DEBT_P25] [float] NULL,
[CUML_DEBT_P10] [float] NULL,
[C150_4_POOLED_SUPP] [float] NULL
```

Here is a link to the data that was imported to SQL Server, it is an excel file. The table in use is structured the same.

Here is some sample data

UNITID  INSTNM  CUML_DEBT_N CUML_DEBT_P90   CUML_DEBT_P75   CUML_DEBT_P25   CUML_DEBT_P10   C150_4_POOLED_SUPP

100654  Alabama A & M University    279701  57500   34308   5860    2172    0.819

100663  University of Alabama at Birmingham 279701  57500   34308   5860    2172    0.710515789

100706  University of Alabama in Huntsville 279701  57500   34308   5860    2172    0.250007692

100724  Alabama State University    279701  57500   34308   5860    2172    0.268253659

100751  The University of Alabama   279701  57499   34308   5860    2172    0.44262623

100830  Auburn University at Montgomery 279701  57490.5 34308   5860    2172    0.627122034

100858  Auburn University   279701  57490.5 34308   5860    2172    0.9674

100937  Birmingham Southern College 279701  57490.5 34308   5860    2172    0.557726923

101073  Concordia College Alabama   279701  57490.5 34308   5860    2172    0.705856303

Here is an example of the desired results, however I need to have it show more than just the 90th percentile, it needs to show all percentiles mentioned

Institution Name                         Cumulative Loan Debt 90th percentile

AOMA Graduate School of Integrative Medicine    $131,335.00

International Academy of Design and Technology-Chicago  $57,500.00

International Academy of Design and Technology-Troy     $57,500.00

International Academy of Design and Technology-Nashville    $57,500.00

Collins College     $57,500.00

Beulah Heights University   $57,499.00

South Coast College     $57,496.00

Westwood College-Denver South   $57,490.50

Westwood College-Anaheim    $57,490.50

Westwood College-Inland Empire  $57,490.50

This shows the highest of the 90th also need lowest and other columns such as CUML_DEBT_P10 etc

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Here is the code I am using so far, however this is only taking from the top 10 not the whole table. 

SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM [dbo].[Cohorts]
ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P10 DESC

this is giving me a somewhat correct answer but as stated only from top 10   

The data result is the top 10 numbers in descending order

Comment: Again I am not very familiar with SQL, please take this into consideration

Comment: Please edit your question to post code. The formatting stinks in the comments and it belongs with the question.

Comment: The biggest issue I see is that your table is not normalized properly. As such you are fighting a poor design to get the data back out. Post some details of your table and we can help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thank you for voting  down. This is a straight forward  question, with all necessary data to provide the correct SQL statement. But hey I guess because people ask for help they should be frowned upon by those in the know.

Comment: It wasn't my downvote but no, you did not provide all the information for others to be able to answer this. We don't know the datatypes, we have no sample data or desired output based on that sample data. I would suggest looking here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I see that you added the table structure. You also mentioned sample data, but that should be data here, not an excel file that we have to go download and massage into consumable data. It doesn't need to be thousands of rows, just enough to convey the problem scope.

Comment: I have added some sample data however I was unsure how to properly format it, apologies. If anyone could help edit to the proper format I would appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not tested,

```
                    SELECT  TOP 10
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P10 ASC) ctr,
                            UNITID,INSTNM,
                            CUML_DEBT_P10,'CUML_DEBT_P10_ASC' Label
                    FROM    [dbo].[Cohorts]


                    SELECT  TOP 10
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P10 DESC) ctr,
                            UNITID,INSTNM,
                            CUML_DEBT_P10,'CUML_DEBT_P10_DESC' Label
                    FROM    [dbo].[Cohorts]


                    SELECT  TOP 10
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P25 ASC) ctr,
                            UNITID,INSTNM,
                            CUML_DEBT_P25,'CUML_DEBT_P25_ASC' Label
                    FROM    [dbo].[Cohorts]


                    SELECT  TOP 10
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P25 ASC) ctr,
                            UNITID,INSTNM,
                            CUML_DEBT_P25,'CUML_DEBT_P25_DESC' Label
                    FROM    [dbo].[Cohorts]


                    SELECT  TOP 10
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P25 ASC) ctr,
                            UNITID,INSTNM,
                            CUML_DEBT_P25,'CUML_DEBT_P25_ASC' Label
                    FROM    [dbo].[Cohorts]


                    SELECT  TOP 10
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P25 ASC) ctr,
                            UNITID,INSTNM,
                            CUML_DEBT_P25,'CUML_DEBT_P25_DESC' Label
                    FROM    [dbo].[Cohorts]



                    SELECT  TOP 10
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P75 ASC) ctr,
                            UNITID,INSTNM,
                            CUML_DEBT_P75,'CUML_DEBT_P75_ASC' Label
                    FROM    [dbo].[Cohorts]

                    SELECT  TOP 10
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P75 ASC) ctr,
                            UNITID,INSTNM,
                            CUML_DEBT_P75,'CUML_DEBT_P75_DESC' Label
                    FROM    [dbo].[Cohorts]



                    SELECT  TOP 10
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P90 ASC) ctr,
                            UNITID,INSTNM,
                            CUML_DEBT_P90,'CUML_DEBT_P90_ASC' Label
                    FROM    [dbo].[Cohorts]


                    SELECT  TOP 10
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P90 ASC) ctr,
                            UNITID,INSTNM,
                            CUML_DEBT_P90,'CUML_DEBT_P90_DESC' Label
                    FROM    [dbo].[Cohorts]
```

Comment: This has helped a lot,  I now have the top ten highest values of each column. However I also need the top ten lowest values of each

Comment: That worked great thank you, could you edit to include columns mentioned above UNITID & INSTNM, these do not need to be sorted etc, just show up next to the associated row

Comment: Thank you that has added the fields needed, however now I am getting a lot of "NULL"'s in the data, I do not understand why as I do not have any NULL values entered

Comment: @Jay I edited the datatype of UNITID from Int to Float, please try again.

Comment: Getting the same result

Comment: @Jay - ok, what specific column does null value appear?

Comment: Appearing in all CUML_DEBT columns

Comment: Just realized, its not plausible using pivot since the top High and Low value also varies in column INSTNM, so making the column in individual select query.

Answer (score 1):

Run each of these separately and you should have the data you need.

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P90 ASC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P90 DESC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P75 ASC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P75 DESC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P25 ASC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P25 DESC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P10 ASC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CUML_DEBT_P10 DESC
```

As the values are of the FLOAT Datatype, you can convert using the STR function.

See below, here the values are ordered by a 7 digit number to two decimal places. You can choose the maximum length of the number you're ordering by (here that's 7 digits) and the number of digits after the point (here, 2 of the (maximum) 7 digits in the number are always after the point), then order by this (as below) and that should resolve the issue.

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(DECIMAL,STR(CUML_DEBT_P90,7,2))  ASC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(DECIMAL,STR(CUML_DEBT_P90,7,2))  DESC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(DECIMAL,STR(CUML_DEBT_P75,7,2))  ASC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(DECIMAL,STR(CUML_DEBT_P75,7,2))  DESC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(DECIMAL,STR(CUML_DEBT_P25,7,2))  ASC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(DECIMAL,STR(CUML_DEBT_P25,7,2))  DESC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(DECIMAL,STR(CUML_DEBT_P10,7,2))  ASC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(DECIMAL,STR(CUML_DEBT_P10,7,2)) DESC
```

Or as Money:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P90,8,2))  ASC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P90,8,2))  DESC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P75,8,2))  ASC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P75,8,2))  DESC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P25,8,2))  ASC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P25,8,2))  DESC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P10,8,2))  ASC
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P10,8,2)) DESC
```

To select UNITID, INSTNM & percentile column whilst retaining the ORDER BY parameter:

```
SELECT TOP 10 UNITID,INSTNM,CUML_DEBT_P90 FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P90,8,2))  ASC
SELECT TOP 10 UNITID,INSTNM,CUML_DEBT_P90 FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P90,8,2))  DESC
SELECT TOP 10 UNITID,INSTNM,CUML_DEBT_P75 FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P75,8,2))  ASC
SELECT TOP 10 UNITID,INSTNM,CUML_DEBT_P75 FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P75,8,2))  DESC
SELECT TOP 10 UNITID,INSTNM,CUML_DEBT_P25 FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P25,8,2))  ASC
SELECT TOP 10 UNITID,INSTNM,CUML_DEBT_P25 FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P25,8,2))  DESC
SELECT TOP 10 UNITID,INSTNM,CUML_DEBT_P10 FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P10,8,2))  ASC
SELECT TOP 10 UNITID,INSTNM,CUML_DEBT_P10 FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P10,8,2))  DESC
```

You can CONVERT the percentile columns in the select so that they display (or move to another table) as the datatype you ordered the rows by to arrive at the top 10's:

```
SELECT TOP 10 UNITID,INSTNM,CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P90,8,2)) FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P90,8,2))  ASC
SELECT TOP 10 UNITID,INSTNM,CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P90,8,2)) FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P90,8,2))  DESC
SELECT TOP 10 UNITID,INSTNM,CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P75,8,2)) FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P75,8,2))  ASC
SELECT TOP 10 UNITID,INSTNM,CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P75,8,2)) FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P75,8,2))  DESC
SELECT TOP 10 UNITID,INSTNM,CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P25,8,2)) FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P25,8,2))  ASC
SELECT TOP 10 UNITID,INSTNM,CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P25,8,2)) FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P25,8,2))  DESC
SELECT TOP 10 UNITID,INSTNM,CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P10,8,2)) FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P10,8,2))  ASC
SELECT TOP 10 UNITID,INSTNM,CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P10,8,2)) FROM COHORTS ORDER BY CONVERT(MONEY,STR(CUML_DEBT_P10,8,2))  DESC
```

Comment: This still does not pull the HIGHEST or LOWEST values, for example the highest value for CUML_DEBT_P90 is 49250 however when running this statement the highest result is 4900

Comment: @Jay are the CUML_DEBT_ columns INT datatype? If not can we find out the datatype?

Comment: They are floats

Comment: Best to convert them, I'll edit my post in a moment.

Comment: @Jay I edited my post to convert the Float datatypes,

Comment: This does not appear to be showing the desired results

Comment: @Jay then as decimals?

Comment: This worked for what I need, however Im seeing through further complication, that the easiest would be just to display one percentile ,column at a time (still including the UNITID and INSTNM). could you please modify the statement to reflect that

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have solved the problems,